# Как правильно удалять body в box2d из world, чтоб не вылетало

Tags: java, разработка-игр, libgdx, box2d

Написал игру на движке libgdx, с использованием box2d для коллизии. Для пуль использовал `Body bullet`, что бы обрабатывать коллизию и урон. Как лучше удалять пули после какого-то времени или коллизии что бы не вылетало

> java: /var/lib/hudson/jobs/libgdx/workspace/trunk/gdx/jni/Box2D/Dynamics/b2World.cpp:134: void b2World::DestroyBody(b2Body*): Assertion 'IsLocked() == false' failed.

Удаления я делал так:

```
if(bullet.isCollision()){
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        while (true) {
                            if (!world.isLocked()) {
                                world.destroyBody(bulletBody);
                                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
}
```

Помимо того что это не работает и ошибка все равно вылетает, если ещё куча минусов. Например, если делать это  для автомата, то будет создаваться очень много потоков, что приводит не только к большому потреблению памяти, но и выбрасывается StackOverflow из-за огромного их количества.
Я попробовал решить эту проблему, добавляя каждую пуля в `ArrayList` и очищаю в 1 потоке этот список.

```
 @Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        for (int i = 0; i < MchAmmunition.destroyList.size(); i++) {
            if (!world.isLocked()) {
                world.destroyBody(MchAmmunition.destroyList.get(i));
                MchAmmunition.destroyList.remove(i);
            } else i--;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Вроде проблема с множеством потоков решена, но ошибка все равно возникает. Что я делаю неправильно?

UPD: ещё 1 ошибка, тоже из-за автомата вылетает

> Exception in thread "Thread-13" java.lang.StackOverflowError

В этом месте `world.step(1 / 60f, 4, 4);`

Comment: Пробовал удалять пули в `render()` методе. Уверен, что вся проблема в том, что удаление происходит во время отрисовки объекта

Comment: Удалять объекты нужно вне world.step(). Т.е. надо сохранить все тела для удаления в список и удалять уже после того как отработает world.step().

Comment: все, заработало, спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, не удаляйте пули отдельным потоком. В документации к LibGDX говорится, что он непотокобезопасен.

Во-вторых, помечайте объекты, которые подлежат удалению и больше не участвуют в игровом процессе каким-нибудь флагом или помещайте ссылки на них в какой-нибудь список. Меняйте их свойства так, чтобы они больше не вызывали коллизий.

Когда закончится симуляция физики в кадре, можно будет удалить эти объекты, обходя этот список.